# Android handler message data being overwritten by next message

Tags: android, handler

Android handler message data being overwritten by next message.How to solve this?

Comment: I have main activity which sends an http request continuously for getting some images. There is a handler which check whether the request is success or not..The second request starts before getting response for first request and the handler message for first request is being overwritten by second one

Comment: How to check whether the first one is finished?And Iam sending request using thread,which runs continuously .

Comment: SO you need a call back method which gets called when server responds.. and inside that you can start another handler.. But ASyncTAsk is preferred..

Comment: There is only one handler.Then how can I start?

Comment: keep class level reference for it... or else start diff handlers for each reference..

Comment: i mean Instance variable.....

Answer (score 0):

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
   switch (msg.what)
   {

   }
}
```